# How to fix an infinite while loop with dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am trying to iterate through the dictionary shown in the picture where I have to retrieve the value of key 'time' whenever the key code = '36' between tag = 'new battery'.

In other words, from the very first time 'tag' == 'new battery' I've to find the time when code == '36' until the next time 'tag' == 'new battery'. It should do this until we finish parsing the dictionary. Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Dictionary picture]

I did a while loop and tried it but i am stuck with an infinite loop. I am brand new to Python. Sorry for being unreadable, but I did the best that I could.

```
for key in d:
       while(d[key]['type'] != '44'): 
          if d[key]['code']=='36':
            time_6=d[key]['time']
            print(time_6)

            countlist.append(time_6)
```

Answer (score 0):

As from my understanding this code will help to resolve your query. We are changing a little bit in your code.you have to reiterate between key when first time and last time tag new battery called.

```
for key in d:
       if(d[key]['type'] == '44'):
           key_bw_nw_battery.append(key)
for f in range(min(key_bw_nw_battery),max(key_bw_nw_battery),1):
       if d[f]['code']=='36':
       time_6=d[f]['time']
       print(time_6)
       countlist.append(time_6)
```

Comment: This assumes the `d` keys are a contiguous range of integers, finds the lowest and highest that have `type` 44, and then does a second pass over those and everything in between. If the keys are like that, the values likely don't belong in a dictionary (nor, typically, should numbers be strings).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no need for this code to use double loops (quadratic behaviour), a `while`, or even the dictionary keys.

```
for item in d.values():
    if item['type'] != '44' and item['code'] == '36':
        time_6 = item['time']
        print(time_6)

        countlist.append(time_6)
```

The key thing to remember about `while` is that something must be changing in the condition it's testing. It doesn't advance on its own like `for` does, so you were testing the same item repeatedly. Since the `while` was inside the `for`, the `for` couldn't advance until the `while` ended (which it never did).